# Multi-Line Array Literal

Tags: node.js, pug

In my Jade template, I'm trying to make an array like so:

```
- var myArray = [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three'
]
```

But it doesn't compile. Anyone know why? Being able to have a multi-line array that I can use as a mixin argument would make my code much less verbose.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code (apart from that `-` one the first line). Should work fine

Comment: @Flambino: I think that leading `-` is a Jade-ism: http://jade-lang.com/

Comment: Wouldn't you need the `-` on every line?

Comment: @muistooshort Ah, hadn't even noticed the `jade` tag. Nor do I know Jade to begin with :)

Comment: How is that less verbose than declaring on a single line? Anyway, I tried different combinations, and it doesn't seem possible to declare on multiple lines. However, this works fine (and is slightly less verbose): `myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three']` (no need for `- var `). (edited for code examples)

Comment: @PuerkitoBio Well that isn't the less-verbose part.. but my array will be large and I may need to edit it a bit, so working on one line will be difficult and unwieldy.

Anyway, what I have up there won't compile. Try it yourself.. it doesn't compile with a - on every line either. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I tried a few different ways and it doesn't seem possible to write it on multiline (the "- var"-less version I mentioned is single line). Have you considered filling the array in javascript and feeding it to your jade template using locals (in `res.render('jadefile', {MYArray: ['one', 'two', 'three']}); `? This way you can write it without the Jade constraints and still use it in your templates and mixins.

Comment: @PuerkitoBio Yes, but that is not ideal because it doesn't make sense to have that information in some other js file. Oh well, I guess I'll make do some other way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jade: declare a variable over multiple lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419312/jade-declare-a-variable-over-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- myArray = ['one']
- myArray.push('two')
- myArray.push('three')
```

If you wanna.

Answer (score 4):

You can use block code:

```
-
    var myArray = [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
    ]

each row, index in myArray
```

Comment: This works, though worth noting that adding a space after the `-` will break this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that :(
https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/405

Answer (score 2):

divesario is right is should look like this:

```
- var myArray = [
-    'one',
-    'two',
-    'three'
- ]
```

Comment: Tried your solution here, got Error `Unexpected token punc «;», expected punc «,» Error at new JS_Parse_Error`. Is this right? -Jade version 0.35.0

Comment: This has saved my day. Btw I'm using it on the latest pug-php

Answer (score 1):

You can, but each line must be prefixed by a '-' - see https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/502