# Jade: declare a variable over multiple lines

Tags: coding-style, pug

I have a jade variable declared like this:

```
BUTTONS = { more_blue: {caption: BUTTONS_CAPTIONS.more, style: BUTTONS_STYLES.blue}, more_red: {caption: BUTTONS_CAPTIONS.more, style: BUTTONS_STYLES.red}, see: {caption: BUTTONS_CAPTIONS.see, style: BUTTON_STYLE_PHOTOS}, see_photos: {caption: BUTTONS_CAPTIONS.see_photos, style: BUTTON_STYLE_PHOTOS}, program : {caption: BUTTONS_CAPTIONS.program, style: BUTTON_STYLE_PROGRAM}, see_program : {caption: BUTTONS_CAPTIONS.see_program, style: BUTTON_STYLE_PROGRAM} }
```

but I would like it to be more readable like this:

```
BUTTONS = { more_blue: {caption: BUTTONS_CAPTIONS.more, style: BUTTONS_STYLES.blue}
        , more_red: {caption: BUTTONS_CAPTIONS.more, style: BUTTONS_STYLES.red}
        , see: {caption: BUTTONS_CAPTIONS.see, style: BUTTON_STYLE_PHOTOS}
        , see_photos: {caption: BUTTONS_CAPTIONS.see_photos, style: BUTTON_STYLE_PHOTOS}
        , program : {caption: BUTTONS_CAPTIONS.program, style: BUTTON_STYLE_PROGRAM}
        , see_program : {caption: BUTTONS_CAPTIONS.see_program, style: BUTTON_STYLE_PROGRAM}
    }
```

but this code doesn't compile even if I add backslashes at the end of each line. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Jade does not support multi-line variables, but you can +1 the request here https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/698 - I think there are many good reasons this is needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Jade now supports multineline variables, as described [in the docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/):

```
-
  list = ["Uno", "Dos", "Tres",
          "Cuatro", "Cinco", "Seis"]
each item in list
  li= item
```

Answer (score 15):

Your question surprised me. I have made some tests in Jade:

This worked (as you said):

`person = {name: 'Bill', age: 50}`

This worked too:

`- person = {name: 'Bill', age: 50}`

This did not (Jade could not compile it:

```
- person = {
-   name: 'Bill',
-   age: 50
- }
```

**This is a good workaround:**

```
- person = {}
- person.name = 'Bill'
- person.age = 50
```